# Operation isFinished always false

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to save my data to plist file using Operation.
I want to implement an asynchronous saving, so I've override the `start()`
But when I try to check wether saving have finished `isFinished` remains false. 
However data has saved successfully, as I planned

```
class OperationDataManager: Operation {

    var user: AppUser?
    override func start() {
        if let plist = Plist(name: "userFile") {
            if let dict = plist.getMutablePlistFile() {
                dict["userName"] = user?.userName
                dict["userInfo"] = user?.userDescription
                dict["userColor"] = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: user?.userColor)
                dict["userImage"] = UIImagePNGRepresentation((user?.userImage)!)
                do {
                    try plist.addValuesToPlistFile(dictionary: dict)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }

        if isFinished == true {
            print("Operation: finished")
        } else {
            print("Operation: not finished")
        }
    }   
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. `isFinished` isn't set to `true` until after `main` completes. It will never be `true` inside `start` or `main`.
2. There's no need for your operation to check `isFinished`. It is finished when `main` gets to the end.

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer. But, I have specific case: I want to show an error alert in case something went wrong. I thought that isFinished flag would be good enough for that. What can you advice in that case?